# using mixins with vuejs and typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I would like to use a global mixin using typescript. My mixin looks like this:

```
Vue.mixin({
  data() {
    return {
      myValue: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.myValue= !this.myValue;
    }
  }
});
```

This gives me the following error: `TS2339: Property 'myValue' does not exist on type 'Vue'.`

If I use the same code inside a compoent `Vue.extend({... same code... })` everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify custom types like so:

```js
// src/vue-shim.d.ts
import Vue from 'vue'

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    myValue: boolean;
  }
}
```

See docs for more details https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins